# Transfer "save data" from Wii-mode to "Wii U-mode"

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, virtual-console

So the question is; I've now got an original Wii. If i play a VC-game on this, i understand that i can transfer this game onto a Wii U in "Wii-mode" if i buy this in the future. So far so good. I also know that i can download the game to "Wii U-mode" for a small fee. The big question is; will I be able to transfer the save-data that i already have for the game in "Wii-mode" onto the newly downloaded version on the "Wii U-mode"?

Comment: It's worth noting the same games available for the VC on the Wii are not necessarily available on the Wii U too. One big example is the Wii U doesn't have any N64 games.

Answer (score 2):

No. The answer is No. The VC games on the Wii U can not access the save game data of VC games within the Wii-mode environment and vice versa.

The VC game save data for games in Wii-mode can only be accessed by the VC games in Wii-mode.

So you'll need to restart your saves from scratch when you play the new Wii U VC copy.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. According to Nintendo's [What Is Transferred During the Wii to Wii U System Transfer Process?](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1125/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDIwMDU3NTI5L3NpZC9icGhMc2libQ%3D%3D) support page, the following data is transferred:

> - Wii Software Save Data
> - WiiWare and Save Data
> - Virtual Console titles and Save Data
> - Add-on Content
> - Wii Points
>
>   - These points will be combined with the points on the target Wii U system, but cannot exceed a combined point total that would exceed 10,000 Wii Points.
> - Wii Shop Channel Account Activity
> - Mii Characters
> - Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection data

According to the [How to Transfer Content from a Wii to a Wii U](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1124/~/how-to-transfer-content-from-a-wii-to-a-wii-u) support page, when you transfer content to the Wii U, it is removed/deleted from the Wii, so you'll only be able to play on the Wii U.

Comment: He was asking if Wii U titles can access the vWii data. It can't.