# Wii save data on the Wii U

Tags: wii-u, virtual-console

I just recently transferred all of my save data from the Wii to the Wii U, and it's my understanding that data for Virtual Console games on the Wii isn't compatitible with the same VC title downloaded directly onto the Wii U.

However, what I'd like to know is, if I downloaded an original Wii title (example: *Super Mario Galaxy*) through Virtual Console and then transferred data from the actual *Super Mario Galaxy* game on my Wii, would I be able to access that data through the VC version on the Wii U? ...Or no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer "save data" from Wii-mode to "Wii U-mode"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198230/transfer-save-data-from-wii-mode-to-wii-u-mode)

Comment: This is a different question.  However, this downvoted [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/198767/51171) to that question seems like it would answer this question.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I'm not concerned with transferring save data from Wii VC to Wii U VC. What I'm wondering is whether save data from original Wii games is compatible with the Wii U's VC.

Comment: ...Unless the answer to the other question does apply to this one, as well.

Answer (score 2):

The save files are compatible if you play the original Wii VC game in Wii mode (an option on the Wii U menu for playing Wii games), but not with the upgraded native Wii U VC versions of the games.